# Gridview sorting not working in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, gridview-sorting

```
<div style="width: 90%; margin-right: 5%; margin-left: 5%; text-align: center">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"
                     runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView7"
                          runat="server"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          DataKeyNames="DetailsId"
                          GridLines="Horizontal"
                          OnRowCommand="GridView7Data_RowCommand"
                          EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"
                          onpageindexchanging="GridView7_PageIndexChanging"
                          AllowPaging="True"
                          AllowSorting="True"
                          onsorting="GridView7_Sorting">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord"
                                     ControlStyle-CssClass="btn"
                                     ButtonType="Button"
                                     Text="Edit"
                                     HeaderText="Edit Record">
                        <ControlStyle CssClass="btn"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"
                                    HeaderText="Name"
                                    SortExpression="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AdminNo"
                                    HeaderText="Admin No"
                                    SortExpression="AdminNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FName"
                                    HeaderText="File Name" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download Link"
                                       ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload7"
                                            runat="server"
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DetailsId") %>'
                                            OnClick="DownloadFile7"
                                            Text="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image1"
                                       ItemStyle-Height="150"
                                       ItemStyle-Width="170">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox24"
                                         runat="server"
                                         Text='<%# Eval("image") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image19"
                                       runat="server"
                                       ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Height="170px"
                                      Width="150px" />
                        <ItemStyle Height="170px"
                                   Width="150px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image2">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox25"
                                         runat="server"
                                         Text='<%# Eval("image2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image20"
                                       runat="server"
                                       ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image2", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Height="170px"
                                      Width="150px" />
                        <ItemStyle Height="170px"
                                   Width="150px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image3">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox26"
                                         runat="server"
                                         Text='<%# Eval("image3") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image21"
                                       runat="server"
                                       ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image3", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Height="170px"
                                      Width="150px" />
                        <ItemStyle Height="170px"
                                   Width="150px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image4"
                                       SortExpression="image4">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"
                                         runat="server"
                                         Text='<%# Eval("image4") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image3"
                                       runat="server"
                                       ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image4", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Height="170px"
                                      Width="150px" />
                        <ItemStyle Height="170px"
                                   Width="150px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image5"
                                       SortExpression="image5">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"
                                         runat="server"
                                         Text='<%# Eval("image5") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image4"
                                       runat="server"
                                       ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image5", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Height="170px"
                                      Width="150px" />
                        <ItemStyle Height="170px"
                                   Width="150px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White"
                            ForeColor="Black"
                            HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label29"
                               runat="server"
                               ForeColor="Red"
                               Text="No Record Found"></asp:Label>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC"
                                  Font-Bold="True"
                                  ForeColor="Black" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333"
                             Font-Bold="True"
                             ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"
                                     ForeColor="#000000" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The above is my code for my Gridview table. And currently my issues is that my sorting isn't working properly. However when it is placed outside of the Updatepanel, it is working.

```
protected void GridView7_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtResult = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        if (dtResult.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Sort"]) == "Asc")
            {
                dtResult.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
                //ViewState["sort"] == "Desc";
            }
            else
            {
                dtResult.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Asc";
                //ViewState["sort"] == "Asc";
            }
            GridView7.DataSource = dtResult;
            GridView7.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

This is my code behind for sorting. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is the error

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233033
Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
   at StarsWebSite.PopGraduateTracking.GridView7Data_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) in C:\Users\133214J\Desktop\latesttt\StarsWebSite\StarsWebSite\PopGenGraduateTracking.aspx.cs:line 109
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowCommand(GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
InnerException:
```

This is my rowCommand method

```
protected void GridView7Data_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("editRecord"))
        {
            lblID.Text = GridView7.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1 = GetData("select FamilyName,Name,Handphone,EmailAddress,Talent,AdminNo,DiplomaName,PMG,PEM,GPA,OSEP,EntryMode,Scholarship,NameOfScholarship,Award1,Quote1,NameOfDegree,UniversityAdmitted,YearAdmitted,SelfEmployed,LatestEmploymentChecked,LatestEmployer,CurrentPosition,CurrentSalary,Remarks, submittedBy from GraduateTracks where DetailsId = '" + int.Parse(lblID.Text) + "'");

            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // DataRow dr = dt.Select("CustomerID=" + GridViewData.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString())[0];
                TBFamilyName.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString(); //
                TBName.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString(); ;
                TBHandphone.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Handphone"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
                TBEmailAddress.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["EmailAddress"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
                TBTalent.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Talent"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
                lblAdminNo.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["AdminNo"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[6].Text);
                TBDiplomaName.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["DiplomaName"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[7].Text);
                TBPMG.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["PMG"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[8].Text);
                TBPEM.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["PEM"].ToString();//HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[9].Text);
                TBGPA.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["GPA"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[10].Text);
                TBOSEP.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["OSEP"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[11].Text);
                TBEntryMode.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["EntryMode"].ToString(); //
                TBScholarship.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Scholarship"].ToString(); ;
                TBNameOfScholarship.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["NameOfScholarship"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
                TBAward1.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Award1"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
                TBQuote1.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Quote1"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
                TBNameOfDegree.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["NameOfDegree"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[6].Text);
                TBUniversityAdmitted.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["UniversityAdmitted"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[7].Text);
                TBYearAdmitted.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["YearAdmitted"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[8].Text);
                TBSelfEmployed.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["SelfEmployed"].ToString();//HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[9].Text);
                TBLatestEmploymentChecked.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["LatestEmploymentChecked"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[10].Text);
                TBLatestEmployer.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["LatestEmployer"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[11].Text);
                TBCurrentPosition.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["CurrentPosition"].ToString(); //
                TBCurrentSalary.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["CurrentSalary"].ToString(); ;
                TBRemarks.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Remarks"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
                lblSubmit.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["submittedBy"].ToString(); //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[10].Text);
            }
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("$('#editModal').modal('show');");
            sb.Append(@"</script>");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `AsyncPostBackTrigger` like this. `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView7" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

Comment: I tried the asyncpostbacktrigger already as you suggested, but it still isnt working.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried keeping breakpoint at `GridView7_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)`. Is it firing?

Comment: I tried to breakpoint at the GridView7_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e), however it brings me to my rowCommand method.

Please view the error i posted on the post.

Comment: What is the value of `e.CommandArgument` in row command

Comment: the commandarguement value is "Name"

Comment: @Lee Aron then how can your "NAME" become an Integer ? `int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error will be this line...

```
protected void GridView7Data_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // Error Converting
}
```

As per above comment you mention your Command Argument is "Name" cannot be convert to Integer..

Easy way to get your RowIndex as per the code below

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "xxx")
    {
        // Why LinkButton because your button type is LinkButton...
        GridViewRow gvr = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as LinkButton;
        int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
    }
}
```

Reference for the LinkButton as below your aspx html

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload7" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DetailsId") %>' 
 OnClick="DownloadFile7" Text="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
```